# Как импортировать модель из главного приложения в blueprint?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Как импортировать модель из общих моделей в blueprint?

**app.py**

```
from yandex_dict.blueprint import yandex_dict
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(yandex_dict, url_prefix='/yandex-dict')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

В app.py импортируется blueprint. И в этом же app создается db. Но т.к. модель унаследована от db.Model, при попытке импортировать ее в blueprint возникает циклический импорт.